# Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat ignores access log configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I've enabled the access log as follows:

```
server.tomcat.basedir=/var/log/my-server/tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=.
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
```

This usally works in my Spring Boot projects, but not in my current project (Spring Boot 2.6.6), where I'm not using `@SpringBootApplication` due to some limitations.

I'm currently using the following annotations for my main class:

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ServletComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { /* ... */})
@ImportAutoConfiguration({WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class,
                ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ...
```

Is there any autoconfiguration I need to import explicitly to configure the embedded tomcat? (`server.address` as well as `server.port` gets already respected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this works. The settings `servlet.tomcat.*` are applied by `TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer`, which is provided by `EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration`.